# Why is the same character compared twice by changing its case to UPPER and then to lower?

Tags: java, string, unicode, comparator

The below code is in Class String in java. I don't understand why the characters from two different strings are compared *twice*.
at first by doing upper case and if that fails by doing lower case.

My Question here is, is it required? If yes, why?

```
  public static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
                                             = new CaseInsensitiveComparator();
        private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator
                implements Comparator<String>, java.io.Serializable {
            // use serialVersionUID from JDK 1.2.2 for interoperability
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 8575799808933029326L;

            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                int n1 = s1.length();
                int n2 = s2.length();
                int min = Math.min(n1, n2);
                for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
                    char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
                    char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
                    if (c1 != c2) {
                        c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
                        c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
                        if (c1 != c2) {
                            c1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1);
                            c2 = Character.toLowerCase(c2);
                            if (c1 != c2) {
                                // No overflow because of numeric promotion
                                return c1 - c2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return n1 - n2;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue might be more complex.

There are characters, where there are *multiple* lowercase codepoints for the same uppercase codepoint or vice versa. So to check for case insensitive match, you **need** to compare both upper and lowercase versions if *one of them* matches.

One example being

> The Greek upper-case letter "Σ" has two different lower-case forms: "ς" in word-final position and "σ" elsewhere.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case)

For upper case not equal but lowercase very much so, [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) supplied this excellent example:

> A better example would be '\u0130' (İ) and 'I'. Passing them through toUpperCase leaves them unchanged (and therefore different), but passing them through toLowerCase results in identical character values

Comment: Can you give an example? Strings and Characters don't deal with Charsets; Charsets are only used to encode these as bytes.

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The Greek upper-case letter "Σ" has two different lower-case forms: "ς" in word-final position and "σ" elsewhere. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case

Comment: but what does that have to do with Charsets?

Comment: toUpperCase does not care about location of a character in a string

Comment: @SamSun No it does not and both ς and σ will be uppercased to Σ. Try the following: `System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('ς'));
  System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase('σ'));`

Comment: I think (no example at hand) there's also chars to have same lowercase while uppercase is different - so comparing all upper isn't good enough sometimes as well

Comment: @Jan perhaps you can say "There are letters for which there are multiple lowercase characters for the same uppercase character" or more precise "There are letters for which there are multiple lowercase codepoints for the same uppercase codepoint"

Comment: A better example would be `'\u0130'` (İ) and `'I'`.  Passing them through toUpperCase leaves them unchanged (and therefore different), but passing them through toLowerCase results in identical character values.

Comment: @VGR except that if using a relevant locale for which these code points are used, such as Turkish locale, will **not** result in identical values. `"I".toLowerCase(new Locale("tr", "TR"))` will output `ı` (\u0131), and not `i`.

Comment: @FelixGlas Correct, and that is why String.toUpperCase and String.toLowerCase are superior to the methods of the same name in Character.  But this question is about the methods of Character.